# Cannot sort my bash functions correctly

Tags: bash, sort

I'm trying to sort my bash functions inside my `.bash_functions` file.

Here is what I type :

```
:g/^function /,/^}$/ s/\n/@@@
:sort /^function /
:%s/@@@/\r/g
```

EDIT0 : Here is some of the input :

```bash
function listVideosFromRSSPodCastPlayList {
    test $# = 1 && {
        local rssURL="$1"
        local wget="$(which wget2 2>/dev/null || which wget)"
#       echo $(youtube-dl -g "$rssURL")
        echo $(curl -s "$rssURL" | egrep -o "https?:[^ <>]*(mp4|webm)" | grep -v .google.com/ | uniq)
    }
}
function getVideosFromRSSPodCastPlayList {
    test $# = 1 && {
        local rssURL="$1"
        local wget="$(which wget2 2>/dev/null || which wget)"
#       $wget $(youtube-dl -g "$rssURL")
        $wget $(curl -s "$rssURL" | egrep -o "https?:[^ <>]*(mp4|webm)" | grep -v .google.com/ | uniq)
    }
}
function jpgRotate {
    test $# = 0 && {
        echo "=> Usage: $FUNCNAME angle file1 file2 file3 ..." >&2
        return 1
    }

    local angle=$1
    shift
    for pic
    do
        extension="${pic/*./}"
        newFile="${pic/.$extension/_ROTATED.$extension}"
        echo "=> Losslessly rotating $pic by $angle degrees into $newFile ..." >&2
        jpegtran -perfect -rotate $angle "$pic" > "$newFile"
        touch -r "$pic" "$newFile"
    done
}
```

Something is wrong with my first command because the functions' code should be converted into one liners.

However, here is a little piece of the output I get instead :

```
function listVideosFromRSSPodCastPlayList {@@@  test $# = 1 && {@@@     local rssURL="$1"@@@        local wget="$(which wget2 2>/dev/null || which wget)"@@@#       echo $(youtube-dl -g "$rssURL")@@@      echo $(curl -s "$rssURL" | egrep -o "https?:[^ <>]*(mp4|webm)" | grep -v .google.com/ | uniq)@@@    }@@@}@@@function getVideosFromRSSPodCastPlayList {
    test $# = 1 && {
        local rssURL="$1"
        local wget="$(which wget2 2>/dev/null || which wget)"
#       $wget $(youtube-dl -g "$rssURL")
        $wget $(curl -s "$rssURL" | egrep -o "https?:[^ <>]*(mp4|webm)" | grep -v .google.com/ | uniq)
    }
}
function jpgRotate {@@@ test $# = 0 && {@@@     echo "=> Usage: $FUNCNAME angle file1 file2 file3 ..." >&2@@@       return 1@@@ }@@@@@@ local angle=$1@@@   shift@@@    for pic@@@  do@@@       extension="${pic/*./}"@@@       newFile="${pic/.$extension/_ROTATED.$extension}"@@@     echo "=> Losslessly rotating $pic by $angle degrees into $newFile ..." >&2@@@       jpegtran -perfect -rotate $angle "$pic" > "$newFile"@@@     touch -r "$pic" "$newFile"@@@   done@@@}@@@function locateBin {
    local regExp="$1"
    shift
    locate "bin/.*$regExp" "$@"
}
...
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you provide the original input? I suspect there are braces inside the functions, causing the schwartzian transform to not cover the entire text

Comment: As expected, you global command range falls short and/or @@@ is a bad delimiter. Maybe try ::: ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add the negative offset `-1` to the second line specifier in the range passed to the first substitution command:

```
                   v
:g/^function /,/^}/- s/\n/@@@
:sort /^function /
:%s/@@@/\r/g
```

Otherwise, the newline at the end of your first function is replaced with `@@@`, which wrongly merges the first line of the second function with the last line of the first one.

---

> the last substition does not work correctly for input lines already ending with @ (for example : echo $@)

In your substitution commands, you need to use a text which doesn't appear in your file.
A good candidate for this kind of transformation is a non-printing character such as a control character like a literal `C-a` whose caret notation is `^A`.
Try this instead:

```
:exe "g/^function /,/^}/- s/\\n/\<c-a>"
:sort /^function /
:exe "%s/\<c-a>/\\r/g"
```

> why bother with the "exe" command, extra quotes and extra backslashes which makes this harder to read ?

The original command that I posted worked on your input file. Now, you say that it doesn't work on another input file which contains `echo $@`, so I use a non-printing character for the replacement.

It works without the `exe` and the extra backslashes, but in this case your replacement is just the text `<c-a>`. And there's no guarantee it will work on some other input file you encounter in the future. OTOH, `^A` is unlikely to appear in your bash script files <sup>1</sup>, so there should be no issue.

If you agree, then you need `exe`, the quotes, and the extra backslashes to make Vim translate `\<c-a>` into `^A` (see `:h expr-quote`).

You can see the result of the translation by replacing `exe` with `echo`:

```
:echo "g/^function /,/^}/- s/\\n/\<c-a>"
g/^function /,/^}/- s/\n/^A
                         ^^

:echo "%s/\<c-a>/\\r/g"
%s/^A/\r/g
   ^^
```

Edit: If you don't like the `:exe` and the extra backslashes, to express `^A` you can write `\%x01` in the pattern and `\="\<c-a>"` in the replacement of the substitutions:

```
:g/^function /,/^}/- s/\n/\="\<c-a>"/
:sort /^function /
:%s/\%x01/\r/g
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If you need to write `^A` in one of your bash script, try `$'\ca'`.

```
$ printf '%s' $'\ca' | od -tc
0000000 001
0000001
```

The syntax is documented in the `QUOTING` section from `$ man bash`:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to
>   string,  with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the
>   ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present,  are  decoded
>   as follows:
>
> ...
>
> \cx    a control-x character

Comment: Something is wrong in the case  where a line ends with `$@`, then after the first substitution command, this line ends with `$@@@@` and the then the last  substitution command replaces `$@@@@` by `\r@` instead of `@\r`, can you please update your last substitution command ?

Comment: @SebMa you dont have to accepf an answer that doesnt work

Comment: @user938271 I'm sorry but it looks I accepted your answer too soon, the last substition does not work correctly for input lines already ending with `@` (for example : `echo $@`)

Comment: @SebMa Use a different placeholder for the line feeds, e.g., `<linefeed>`.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer I'm french and don't know what a "placeholder" is. I've learned using vim on the job. Do you some beginners' tutorial on vim placeholders ?

Comment: @SebMa A "placeholder" is nothing specific to Vim. I meant the three commercial-at signs, which you used as a marker for end-of-line.

Comment: @SebMa Does this fix the other issue? : https://0x0.st/zV2k.txt If not, you need to provide a real input example.

Comment: @SebMa Sorry, the previous snippet will not work. Try this one instead: https://0x0.st/zV2n.txt

Comment: @user938271 The last snippet works even without the "exe" command, extra quotes and extra backslashes. But why bother with the "exe" command, extra quotes and extra backslashes which makes this harder to read ?

Comment: @user938271 OK, I understand but what about the [<linefeed> placeholder](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20879/cannot-sort-my-bash-functions-correctly#comment36542_20880) that JürgenKrämer suggested, doesn't it make the whole thing easier to code like this :   `g/^function /,/^}$/-1 s/\n/<linefeed>/ ?`

Comment: @SebMa You can use whatever replacement you like in your text, including `<linefeed>`, `@foobar@`, `!this@will§neverµappearùinçfileéat_least^I-hope`. As long as it doesn't appear in your text.

Comment: FWIW, as soon as I saw you used `@@@`, I thought it would be better to use a control character, because that's what I always do when I have to perform a temporary substitution which I need to undo. But I didn't mention it, because I suspected you wouldn't like the code, and because I thought I was over precautious; it turns out I was not since you immediately found a file for which the substitutions didn't work as expected.

Comment: So now, I post what I wanted to initially, because that's what I use all the time. I never use a temporary replacement using printing characters, because it caused me too many issues in the past, and because Vimscript has enough pitfalls to avoid. But again, use whatever you prefer.

Comment: @user938271 Thanks for all the explanations. I've just accepted your answer :)